# PHP PDO prepared statements for where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Suppose i have code like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ? ORDER BY id desc limit 1
 $query = $this->prepare($q);
```

i need to put the following conditions to the where condition:

```
(id=1 and age=20) or (x=50 and y='yes')
```

But `$query->execute(array("(id=1 and age=20) or (x=50 and y='yes')"));` is not fetching any vaues.
How can I put prepared statements for **'where' clause** condition. Kindly help me to fix it.

Comment: Placeholders are for values, not for expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

input parameters will be values not expression.. you can try the following..

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (id=? and age=?) or (x=? and y=?) ORDER BY id desc limit 1
$query = $this->prepare($q);
$query->execute(array(1, 20, 50, 'yes'));
```